# Why are client HTTP connections not getting closed?

Tags: node.js, http, server, mocha.js

I have a `node.js` (12.18.4) server application which listens for HTTP connections. Our tests use `mocha` and `request`, and we make many connections to the server. At the end of the testing, we shut down the server but first we make sure that all connections have been closed by calling `server.getConnections` and asserting that the value is 0. The vast majority of the time it is, but *sometimes* the value returned is non-zero, usually around 60-70. We make far more than 60-70 requests during the tests. No tests failed or got stuck.

How can I determine why the server thinks these connections are still around?

Comment: How exactly do you shut down the server at the end of testing?

Comment: After the `getConnections` check we just use `server.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I question the value of asserting on the number of active server connections — if all of your tests have completed successfully, what difference does it make if your OS is slow to clean up some TCP connections?

At any rate, I'd ditch the `getConnections` check and just call `server.close(cb)`.

The `close` callback is invoked immediately if there are no active connections, or it waits until all remaining connections have closed before firing.  A test timeout should occur if the connections don't drain.